# Can I still use my old WP7 device as a PDA and still purchase apps?

Tags: functionality, store

My wife is thinking of switching away from her WP7 device. I know she'll still be able to use her existing apps and wifi, and sync MP3s via Zune Charging apps to our carrier account has never worked on her phone (works fine on mine), but she doesn't purchase nearly as many as I do.

Will she still be able to purchase apps and music from the Marketplace via credit card without a SIM or data plan? What about her Xbox Music Pass? Can she still use the phone as a general PDA and music player in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can still use it without a sim; I don't have a microsim for my phone yet but I am still able to sync it via zune and purchase apps through the store.

Comment: Me too: though I haven't set up a credit card and only "buy" free apps. How do you pay for things?

Comment: When I try to buy a paid app, it will ask me to add a credit card.
Does it normally charge it to your phone provider account and not a credit card?

Comment: Good to hear. How about the Xbox Music Pass? Do you know if that's tied to the carrier/SIM or the Live ID assigned to the phone?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried using the Xbox music pass.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe The Xbox Music Pass is assigned to the live ID on the device, so you should be fine.

Comment: @AG The MS Store charges are dependant on how its configured, I believe in the states you can choose your payment provider to be the operator, but that's uncommon here in the UK leaving card/paypal.

Comment: Please consider marking as accepted :)